# Get rid of switch statement

Tags: oop, switch-statement, refactoring

recently working on a task and I encountered a problem which I am stuck on, the matter is with switch statement as follows:

```
private static final Double FIRST_HOUR_COST = 1.0;
private static final Double SECOND_HOUR_COST = 2.0;
private static final Double CONVERSION_RATE = 1.5

@Override
public double calculateReservationCost(Reservation reservation)
{
    int hours = DateUtils.hoursDifference(reservation.getStartTime(), reservation.getStopTime()) + 1;

    switch(hours)
    {
        case 1:
            return FIRST_HOUR_COST;
        case 2:
            return FIRST_HOUR_COST + SECOND_HOUR_COST;
        default:
            return FIRST_HOUR_COST +
                   SECOND_HOUR_COST +
                   countEachNextHour(SECOND_HOUR_COST, 2, hours);
    }
}
```

I tried probably every solution I could find on stack but wasn't able to adjust it to my needs (map with functions as values, single equation etc). Hoping there is any other way to replace it in an efficient way without breaking any OOP rules.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you think the switch is a bad solution, or is it not working?

Comment: This question probably would fit better on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site, but since you have posted here, I will say that there is nothing wrong with your `switch` statement.  It's easy to read, clean, and probably the best way to do this.  You could use a series of if-else statements, or even a ternary expression, but both are uglier IMHO.

Comment: Looks good to me. It's readable and it is easy to understand what it does. I wouldn't touch it.

Comment: I mean it seems for me a little bit too expressive when I look on it, but maybe it's just myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the Switch Statement with the Strategy pattern. This will allow you to add new strategies in the future without having a long switch statement.

Comment: There won't be new cases in a switch statement, only new implementations with different ratios.